# curl_exec not working with Veeva Vault integration into CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I have a site written in CakePHP which needs to download files from Veeva Vault. I inherited this authentication function from someone else which is supposed to return a session id from Veeva, but it returns false on curl_exec() when it should return true. I was told the function worked with a test file outside CakePHP so I'm thinking its something Cake related.

```
private function Auth()
{
    try {

    $url = self::VVURL . '/auth?username=' . self::VVUSERNAME . '&password=' . self::VVPASS;

    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($json_response != true) {
        throw new Exception (curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
    }
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($status != 200)
    {
      die('Error:  call to URL $url failed with status "' . $status .'", response "' . $json_response. '", curl_error "' . curl_error($curl) . '", curl_errno "'  . curl_errno($curl). '"');
    }
    else 
    {
      //Enable following line to DEBUG
      //print_r($json_response);
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    $return = json_decode($json_response);
    foreach($return as $k => $v)
    {
      if($k == 'sessionId')
        $this->sessID = $v;
    }

    return $this->sessID;

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

curl_init($url) returns **resource(148, curl)** . I don't know if that's right or not.

curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) returns 200, so I know that's good.

curl_exec($curl) returns false.

The catch returned:

Fatal Error
Error: Curl failed with error #56: Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data
File: C:\wamp\www\content\app\Vendor\veeva\veeva.php
Line: 109
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any helpful Veeva documentation.

**SOLUTION**

I needed to add the following curl option before running curl_exec(),

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

This returned a proper json response. Though it could not be directly entered into json_decode() and had to be edited as such:

```
$json_utf8 = utf8_decode($json_response);
$return = json_decode(str_replace("?", "", $json_utf8));
```

Comment: PROBLEM: Function curl_exec may disabled. What to do?

SOLUTION: In order to eliminate this error message you need to do ONE of the following things: Remove the curl_exec string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don’t have an access to the php.ini* file Change hosting provider which allows the running of the curl_exec function.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION**

I needed to add the following curl option before running curl_exec(),

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
```

This returned a proper json response. Though it could not be directly entered into json_decode() and had to be edited as such:

```
$json_utf8 = utf8_decode($json_response);
$return = json_decode(str_replace("?", "", $json_utf8));
```